# Passing radio button to FPDF from contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf, contact-form-7

I have a radio button with two values that can be chosen. M or Z. The thing is that everythings works, but i dont think that it recognizes the variable, because whatever i put into 'else' it gets executed. So when i press submit, even if i choose button with value M or Z, i will get the results $type = X and $sir = 90.

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $first_name = $submission->get_posted_data("first-name");
    $last_name = $submission->get_posted_data("last-name");
    $email = $submission->get_posted_data("email-838");
    $radio = $submission->get_posted_data("radio-474");
}

  if($radio == M) {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '50';
  } elseif ($radio == Z) {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '70';
         }

else {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '90'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was working with fpdf and contact form 7 I was only able to get the value of a variable by using `$_POST[''];` So if you try

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first-name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['"last-name'];
    $email = $_POST['email-838'];
    $radio = $_POST['radio-474'];
}

  if($radio == M) {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '50';
  } elseif ($radio == Z) {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '70';
         }

else {
          $type = 'X';
          $sir = '90'; }
```

it might work for you.